# Playframework: Is it possible to pass parameters to a Model's getter in the template?

Tags: groovy, playframework, playframework-1.x

I don't know how to describe it, so the question title may not make much sense.

Say, I have a class named `User`:

```
class User {
    public String name;

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getName(long level){
        // Calculate the name with level.
        return name;
    }
}
```

I know I could use `${user.name}` in the template to invoke the `getName()` function, but what if I want to pass a `level` to invoke `getName(long level)` in template ?

Is there any alternative looks like `${user.name(123)}`

Is it possible to make it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need

```
${user.getName(123)}
```